# Why I don't have to flush the output buffer while using printf everytime?

Tags: c

In this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("I");
    printf("am");
    printf("a");
    printf("good");
    printf("boy");
    return 0;
}
```

Why I don't have to use `fflush(stdout)` every time? I mean how the strings are getting printed in the console if there is no new line(since new line flushes the output buffer).Or is it the buffer is getting full so I don't to do it explicitly?If so how?

Comment: Simply because your buffer get's flushed when the program quits. Step through your code with a debugger, and you probably will see no output until the program quits. This is higly implementation dependent, on some systems there is no output buffering.

Comment: Put a `while(1);` at the end of function, before `return 0;` and see what happen.

Comment: @LPs Tried that,and the cursor just blinks after 'y'.Care to explain why?

Comment: @avistein See Michael Walz's comment.

Comment: @MichaelWalz If it's flushed when the program quits,then what is the use of `fflush(stdout)`,since everything will be flushed at the end?

Comment: You have a good answer and a good comment by @MichaelWalz to understand why `stdout` is not flushed. BTW another little trick for your code with my previous modification: change `"boy"` into `"boy\n"`

Comment: Keep in mind that most programs are longer than 10 lines. There are several instances (embedded applications, servers, etc) where there is no "end" or "quit" to the program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the `stdout` stream is buffered, so as Michael commented you will see the output(*mostly*) when the program quits. If you want to immediatel print the output the you can use `fprintf` like

```
fprintf(stderr, "my Text");
```

See the ISO C99 section 7.19.3/3:

> When a stream is unbuffered, characters are intended to appear from
>   the source or at the destination as soon as possible. Otherwise
>   characters may be accumulated and transmitted to or from the host
>   environment as a block.
>
> When a stream is fully buffered, characters are intended to be
>   transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a buffer
>   is filled.
>
> When a stream is line buffered, characters are intended to be
>   transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line
>   character is encountered.
>
> Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to
>   the host environment when a buffer is filled, when input is requested
>   on an unbuffered stream, or when input is requested on a line buffered
>   stream that requires the transmission of characters from the host
>   environment.
>
> Support for these characteristics is implementation-defined, and may
>   be affected via the setbuf and setvbuf functions.

Comment: So when do I have to use the `fflush(stdout)` if the buffer is automatically cleared at program's end?

Comment: @avistein: There might be the need to see some data, before the program ends?

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: @avistein: If  none comes to your mind, you probably need none ... :-/

Comment: @avistein use case: you printf "Please wait this may take up to 1 minute to compute", then you do some lenghty calculation. Do I need to write more?

Comment: @MichaelWalz alright,that means when we do need the answer to be printed immediately,then I gotta use `fflush` ,right?

Comment: @avistein yes, `fflush(stdout)` flushes the output buffer when called.